# video on top of overlay appears still opaque

Tags: css, angularjs, video, overlay

```
  div#overlay(ng-show="play_video")
    div#video_container
```

on click of a button, I set play_video=true,
which dynamically builds the video tag (source needs to be constructed dynamically:

```
<video controls="">
   <source src="/videos/test7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

All works fine, but my video appears opaque, as if behind the overlay. I've checked many solutions which tell about z-index and position, but I still don't get it right. What do I get the video in front of everything? I also tried to put position: absolute and the highest z-index on the video element itself - no success.
http://jsfiddle.net/5LGD9/

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 100;
}

#video_container {
    z-index:  2000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the video_container as sibling of the overlay did the trick:

```
div#overlay(ng-show="play_video")
div#video_container
```